# What is 02 in the magisk patched vbmeta.img?

Tags: rooting, root-access, selinux, magisk, systemless-root

According to the [Additional Info](https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/install.html#additional-info) given for rooting the Android device that doesn't have ramdisk but can be rooted via recovery: we need an `empty vbmeta.img` and I am trying to check what it actually contains. I understand the hex that removed the verification flags from the `original vbmeta.img` and the hex for `avbtool 1.1.0` but there is a hex `00 02` at `00000070` which I didn't get why it is there.

Does anybody can explain this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/intel/kernelflinger/blob/master/avb/libavb/avb_vbmeta_image.h) piece of source code by Intel, there is an `uint32_t` starting at position`0x78` (120) and ending at `0x7b` (124). This location is marked as "flags from the AvbVBMetaImageFlags enumeration", which "must be set to zero if the vbmeta image is not a top-level image".

On to the enumeration itself. `AvbVBMetaImageFlags` is defined in the same file and the flag set by Magisk is `0x00000002` (2). From the source, we see that the corresponding value, therein expressed as `1 << 1`, is called `AVB_VBMETA_IMAGE_FLAGS_VERIFICATION_DISABLED`, which is quite self-explanatory.

In short, Magisk is modifying that value knowingly, in order to disable a verification that would likely prevent your device from booting a modified image.