# What is the format of Android M1 Initial Preview system.img?

Tags: android-emulator, developer-preview

I download Android Emulator M1 Initial Preview from https://github.com/google/android-emulator-m1-preview/releases

Inside the .app file I found `api30-gphone-arm64-v8a/system.img` which isn't a yaffs2 nor sparse file:

```
./unyaffs2 /tmp/android-wip/system.img /tmp/android-wip/system-img/
unyaffs2-0.2.8: image extracting tool for YAFFS2
image size (3232759808) is NOT a mutiple of 2048 + 64

operation incomplete
files contents may be broken
```

```
simg2img system.img.ext4 system.img
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Failed to read sparse file
```

So what is the format of such file?

**Updates:**
Based on the direction from @Robert, I can see that the file is an fdisk image:

```
$ fdisk -lu system.img
Disk system.img: 3,1 GiB, 3232759808 bytes, 6313984 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 41F73643-DBCB-41A1-A27E-9FDB53578618

Device      Start     End Sectors Size Type
system.img1  2048    4095    2048   1M Linux filesystem
system.img2  4096 6311935 6307840   3G Linux filesystem
```

Now, it's unclear what format of the partition inside, because mount it as a regular linux partition fails:

```
$ sudo mount -o loop,offset=1048576 system.img /mnt/android-1
mount: /mnt/android-1: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop17, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

gparted also doesn't understand the partition:

[image]

Comment: The file is not a partition but a whole disk. You can open it with fdisk and see that it contains multiple partitions.

Comment: @Robert Thanks. Do you have further information on what kind of format for each partition? It doesn't seem to be ext4 partitions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

wrong offset, partition start at sector 4096. you can use `kpartx` instead

newer android running dynamic partitions. the super partition can be unpacked with [Dynamic Partition Tools](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/partition_tools)

furthermore partitions are flagged as read-only, therefore `mount -r` flag is required

```
sudo -i

git clone https://github.com/AndroidDumps/Firmware_extractor.git
PATH=$PATH:$(realpath Firmware_extractor/tools/Linux/bin)

mkdir -p /mnt/android-1/system_root ../extracted
kpartx -av system.img
lpunpack -p system /dev/mapper/loop2p2 ../extracted

mount -t ext4 -o loop,ro,noexec,noload,noatime ../extracted/system.img /mnt/android-1/system_root
thunar /mnt/android-1/system_root
```

(or whatever `kpartx` tell you 2nd partition is mapped)

---

in case you need to make ext4-dedup/logical partition writeable, increase partition first, then duplicate shared blocks

```
cd ../extracted
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1G seek=1 count=0 of=system.img
resize2fs system.img 1G
e2fsck -E unshare_blocks system.img
```

you should be able to `mount -w` afterwards

---

**re-packing** requires new `vbmeta` signature with [avbtool.py](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/master/avbtool.py) stored in first partition `system.img1` start at sector 2048 (which goes too far here)

[superrepack](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4120963) third-party cross-platform tool for easy unpack/repack `system.img2` is recommended to automatize the whole re-packing process

you can however do it manually with `lpmake` (requires all partitions to be unpacked into `../extracted` see above step `lpunpack`)
[source](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4196625)

```
resize2fs -M system.img
e2fsck -yf system.img
lpmake --metadata-size 65536 --super-name super --metadata-slots 1 --device super:3229614080 --group main:2369171456 --partition system:readonly:787050496:main --image system=system.img --partition vendor:readonly:83619840:main --image vendor=vendor.img --partition product:readonly:1366814720:main --image product=product.img --partition system_ext:readonly:131686400:main --image system=system_ext.img --sparse --output super.img
```

Comment: It failed with this error:
```
mount -t ext4 -o loop,rw,noatime /dev/mapper/loop19p2 /mnt/android-1/system
mount: /mnt/android-1/system: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop20, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

Comment: Thanks for the enlightening answer. I was able to mount the image and changing the content inside now

Comment: you won't be able to run modified partition unless avb/dm-verity is disabled. maybe it's already sufficient to set the [flag 2](https://wiki.postmarketos.org/wiki/Android_Verified_Boot_(AVB)#Disabling_verified_boot) in system.img1 with hex editor which will instruct to skip hashtree verification (never tested myself, but that's what magisk does) https://android.stackexchange.com/q/221756

Comment: superrepack come with a warning from the author just yesterday: `I have bad news for you! This tool is dangerous! Do not use please! What I have found now while checked modified partition with e2fsck, found a ton of "Multiply-claimed blocks already reassigned or cloned.", when I do e2fsck repair it got repaired but bad news is some files is deleted from partition`

Comment: just wait a few days it will solved soon :) you can meanwhile go the official way as descriped by Brepro1, it's well tested

Comment: I was able to produce the new super image with lpmake:
```
lpmake --metadata-size 65536 --super-name super --metadata-slots 1 --device super:3229614080 --group main:2366435328 --partition system:readonly:784314368:main --image... --sparse --output super.simg
```

How can I pack it back as a super partition together with a vbmeta partition like the original one?

Comment: (The original one is an fdisk file with 2 partition vbmeta of 1M and super of 3G)

Comment: *cat super.img > /dev/mapper/loop2p2*

Comment: The emulator won't boot with the new system.img generated by the method above. I go ahead and hex patched the byte to disable verification but I guess I don't know enough to make the correct patch: https://imgur.com/8remGKm

Comment: superrepack doesn't work for me neither. I'm getting `clone_file: Could not allocate block in ext2 filesystem returned from clone_file_block` while running superrepack on the emulator - I guess because I'm running it on emulator, not real device?

Comment: there is also dm-verity one must disable in fstab