# Trying to (fast) boot: Error verifying the received boot.img

Tags: twrp, fastboot

As described in [this answer by @irfan-latif](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/203913/18559), I am trying to boot (without flashing) my Google Pixel 3a into TWRP via the following command:

`fastboot boot twrp-3.5.2_9-0-sargo.img`

This failed with the following messages:

```
Sending 'boot.img' (65536 KB)                      OKAY [  2.028s]
Booting                                            FAILED (remote: 'Error verifying the received boot.img: Invalid Parameter')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

The only things I found on this topic are:

- [A thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Pixel3a/comments/ga7l5h/twrp_not_booting_in_android_p/) which wasn't really solved as they moved from `boot`ing to `flash`ing which eventually worked for them, but I'm interested in booting only at this point.
- [A thread on XDA Dev](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/attempted-to-boot-twrp-error-verifying-the-received-boot-img-invalid-parameter.4019469/) which basically ended with ["TWRP for Pixel 3/3XL on Adroid 10 does not work and will not until they release a compatible version"](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/attempted-to-boot-twrp-error-verifying-the-received-boot-img-invalid-parameter.4019469/post-81198795).  Note also that this may not apply to me as I have Android 11 (RQ3A.210605.005 to be precise) and a newer TWRP version.
- [A Github issue](https://github.com/TeamWin/android_device_google_crosshatch/issues/5) from 4 Sep 2020, closed with the message "android 11 is not supported yet." (though this is for a slightly different device).

What caused the error, can it be resolved, and if so, how?

### P.S. Further details:

```
$ adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 31.0.2-7242960
$ fastboot --version
fastboot version 31.0.2-7242960
```

- I have unlocked the bootloader.
- I also tried booting the LineageOS recovery which appears to work, but continues starting Android normally instead of TWRP:

```
$ fastboot -v boot lineage-18.1-20210608-recovery-sargo.img
Sending 'boot.img' (65536 KB)                      OKAY [  2.004s]
Booting                                            OKAY [  7.085s]
Finished. Total time: 9.156s
```

Comment: you can't boot from fastboot if that option is disabled intentionally. usually workaround is temporary flashing twrp to boot, and immediately restore original boot partition before installing twrp into ramdisk. the other issue is kernel related

Comment: @alecxs Just so I understand this: If booting from fastboot was disabled, wouldn't the Booting step (when trying to boot the LineageOS recovery) fail in the same way? Or is the fact that it says OKAY for the LineageOS recovery related to the kernel? Sorry, still wrapping my head around how this all works!

Comment: @alecxs So the LineageOS verifies OKAY (supposedly having been signed by the correct key) but TWRP doesn't? Will AVB prevent me from also `flash`ing TWRP (or being able to boot TWRP after it's been flashed)? No, I haven't flashed the avbmeta partition, would I need an avbmeta.img (where from?) to be able to boot TWRP? If that's what I have to do, I'd also like to backup the current avbmeta before, how?

Comment: @alecxs Also, [this section in the AVB docs](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/avb/+/master/README.md#Locked-and-Unlocked-mode) suggests that verification shouldn't fail when in UNLOCKED state, which I think my phone is (at least that's what it says).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Verified Boot and generation of vbmeta image](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219968/android-verified-boot-and-generation-of-vbmeta-image)

Comment: yeah if bigdiff says android 11 not supported it's pointless to agonize over. my guess is avb can't patched because of vbmeta_vendor is inside dynamic partition. you can try to [unpack](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236065/what-is-the-format-of-android-m1-initial-preview-system-img) and analyze super.img just for fun. btw i don't even know 3a has super partition at all, haven't checked. just wait some months maybe devs already working on it

Comment: you can do a simple test: unpack + repack LineageOS boot.img with [AIK](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2073775) using flags --origsize --original without modifying anything. if that fails to boot it's avb

Comment: Does Magisk even work?

Comment: Exact same issue here on an Android 12 pixel 3. Found the same links as you, and no comment are really giving a working solution

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this helps anyone or not but,  I had the same issue and after two day's of attempting different things I decided to start from scratch but realized if I used the original factory image (Android 9) from:
https://developers.google.com/android/images

It would likely be a lot easier to manipulate.  Turns out that was all I had to do.  Once I flashed it back to original everything else worked without a problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To make this more useful, could you please add exact steps you followed? I.e. commands entered on the command line, in the correct order? What exactly do you mean by "flashed it back to original"?

Answer (score 0):

Up to now, the newest factory img for Pixel3 is `SP1A.210812.016.C2 (8618562)` , you can flash it through [Android flashing website](https://flash.android.com/). I can boot by `twrp_3.7.0_12-0-blueline.img`, you can have a try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! As I stated in my question, I would like to *boot* the image, explicitly *without flashing* it.