# Which format the system images for avd are in

Tags: file-system, avd-manager

After downloading an image for android virtual device via avdmanager there are system.img userdata.img ramdisk.img and kernel_ranchu in system images folder. Which format are they in and how to read/mount them outside avd?

My investigation so far:

As many people here and over the internet suggests they are sparse images. But they are nit. Simg2img hence doesn't work.
System.img is not a raw ext4 image either.

`file ststem.img`returns dos/mbr boot sector. With `fdisk -l` there are 2 partitions in the gpt partitioned image, labeled as linux partition.But setting up `losetup` none can be mounted. Even `file -s` doesn't recognize partitions. Interestingly first partition os from offset 2048 to 4096. Second is the rest.
These images are definitely not encrypted as `strings` returns readable data like app names script contents.

So I'm wondering what kind of filesystem that can be.

Ps: the sw apply for both google play and aosp devices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the format of Android M1 Initial Preview system.img?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236065/what-is-the-format-of-android-m1-initial-preview-system-img)