# Repacked modified super.img - can't see new files

Tags: root-access, boot, dm-verity

I got a Chinese phone with an MTK6761 SoC, running Android 13 (has the virtual A/B partition and DM-verity/AVB enabled). I managed to unlock the bootloader and root it through Magisk and MTKClient tool running on Manjaro Linux. So far the only "issue" with that is that as I have seccfg modified, I have the annoying message at boot stating that the partitions are corrupted (because of dm-verity). In that regard, I tried disabling dm-verity through the usual methods with no luck.

The problem that I am facing is as follows:

I am attempting to modify the bootanimation file, which is inside the "product" virtual partition. I found that it is inside super.bin, so I unpacked it using the lpunpack commandline application with the command:

```
lpunpack super.bin ./Images`
```

Then, I found there was an image, `product_a.img` which has the `bootanimation.zip`, so I increased the allocated size by 10 MB with the following commands:

```
e2fsck -f product_a.img

fallocate -l 2275078144 product_a.img

resize2fs product_a.img 555439
```

Then, I mounted it to a folder named "product" with the following command:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 -o loop,rw product_a.img product
```

To access and modify its content I used Thunar Root and replaced the bootanimation file with my custom file. Then I unmounted the file using sudo umount product and repacked everything with the following command:

```
lpmake 
    --super-name super 
    --metadata-size 65536 
    --metadata-slots 2 
    --device super:5368709120 
    --group main:4504506368 
    -p "product_a:none:2275078144:main" -i "product_a=./product_a.img" 
    -p "product_b:none:0:main" -i "product_b=./product_b.img" 
    -p "system_a:none:1678229504:main" -i "system_a=./system_a.img" 
    -p "system_b:none:139591680:main" -i "system_b=./system_b.img" 
    -p "vendor_b:none:0:main" -i "vendor_b=./vendor_b.img" 
    -p "vendor_a:none:411607040:main" -i "vendor_a=./vendor_a.img" 
    -virtual-ab 
    --output ./super.img
```

I must say that I had to place vendor_b before vendor_a because it being a 0 byte partition made **lpmake** complain if it was the last partition. To get the actual size of each partition I used the result of "stat" command for each, and I used a metadata-size of 65536 as it was "recommended" online.

Lastly, I flashed it to the phone through MTKClient:

```
 python mtk w super super.img
```

The partition was written successfully and the device started correctly but I could not see any changes. So I dumped once again the super image from the phone, and I verified the changes were actually applied to the ROM, and that is when I got really confused. I also tried removing files and adding files to the partition, only to find that the device do not see the changes but they seem to be there when I dump it back tu my PC.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: disable dm-verity/[FEC](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/verifiedboot/dm-verity#fec) first

Comment: I tried disabling dm-verity using the command **fastboot --disable-verity --disable-verification flash vbmeta vbmeta.img** using the vbmeta_a.img image that I dumped with MTKClient, but that always results in a bootloop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you could try to flash vbmeta_a and vbmeta_b instead

Comment: I tried flashing vbmeta_a and b with the parameters to disable. The phone does its boot process (shows boot logo) but when it has to show the boot animation it turns off. Same thing happened when I tried to patch vbmeta_a with Magisk and flashed it with MTKClient. Perhaps I have to patch some other partition as well?

Comment: Maybe. can you double check vbmeta is disabled? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221756/what-is-02-in-the-magisk-patched-vbmeta-img

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer. What I tried was running the fastboot command to disable and then dumped the vbmeta file again. Compared both files with HxD, the only difference is at offset 70, what was a 0x03 on the original is now 0x00. Tried to find the word "verity" but it does not appear on any.  The only words I can make out are avbtool 1.2.0 and a word "fingerprint" I suppose is the for the key to verify. There are other vbmeta partitions (vendor, system) shall those be patched?

Comment: yes, patch all these partitions with HxD manually and give it a try

Comment: I tried patching every partition as you said but I can't find "verity" on any of those images. What do I have to replace in HxD? By the way, thank you for your help.

Comment: see the hex 02 on the right picture

Comment: I tried setting to 0x02 on that position on all three files. Also I tried writing 0x00 on the other positions as shown on that thread but in either case, it keeps boot looping. I believe there is something different with this device that I am missing.

Comment: dig more into FEC