# How to disable avb on devices that use EROFS on super?

Tags: samsung, cyanogenmod, rooting, rom-flashing, stock-android

I understand and can patch avb on devices that don't use EROFS filesystem as we normally just edit `/etc/fstab` which is normally in boot.img or boot.bin or in boot_a.bin with devices that A/B or plain images.

The  main issue I have is that when you have just modified your system or super your changes don't appear untill you have disabled avb, especially on devices that no longer use ext4 images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is 02 in the magisk patched vbmeta.img?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/221756/what-is-02-in-the-magisk-patched-vbmeta-img)

Comment: Intresting, it means avb is in vbmeta.img will dump it and look inside.